# Countdown Timer Clocks In Separate Divs Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Can't get the vars getElementById to work in there new elements. it was working when it was in one element but now trying to make them have there own elements so it is easier to be responsive

http://codepen.io/riwakawebsitedesigns/pen/cqnmD

```
<div class="row">
<div class="block-lg-3 block-md-3 block-sm-3 block-xs-12">
<div class="module">
<h2>Days</h2>  
<div id="days"></div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="block-lg-3 block-md-3 block-sm-3 block-xs-12">
<div class="module">
<h2>Hours</h2>  
<div id="hours"></div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="block-lg-3 block-md-3 block-sm-3 block-xs-12">
<div class="module">
<h2>Minutes</h2>  
<div id="minutes"></div>
</div>  
</div>
<div class="block-lg-3 block-md-3 block-sm-3 block-xs-12">
<div class="module">
<h2>Seconds</h2>  
<div id="seconds"></div>
</div>
</div>

// set the date we're counting down to
var target_date = new Date('July, 31, 2014').getTime();

// variables for time units
var days, hours, minutes, seconds;

// get tag element
//var clock = document.getElementById('clock');
var days = document.getElementById('days');
var hours = document.getElementById('hours');
var minutes = document.getElementById('minutes');
var seconds = document.getElementById('seconds');

// update the tag with id "countdown" every 1 second
setInterval(function () {

// find the amount of "seconds" between now and target
var current_date = new Date().getTime();
var seconds_left = (target_date - current_date) / 1000;

// do some time calculations
days = parseInt(seconds_left / 86400);
seconds_left = seconds_left % 86400;

hours = parseInt(seconds_left / 3600);
seconds_left = seconds_left % 3600;

minutes = parseInt(seconds_left / 60);
seconds = parseInt(seconds_left % 60);

// format countdown string + set tag value
days.innerHTML = '<span class="days">' + days + 'Days</span>';
hours.innerHTML = '<span class="hours">' + hours + 'Hours</span>';
minutes.innerHTML = '<span class="minutes">' + minutes + 'Minutes</span>';
seconds.innerHTML = '<span class="seconds">' + seconds + 'Seconds</span>';

}, 1000);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have overwritten the variable `days`, which was the div element, with the variable `days`, which contains the number of days.

Maybe change the div element variable to `daysContainer`.

Comment: Working version of your code, with my suggested change: http://jsfiddle.net/DCQN2/